# Can nodes communicate with each other when each node uses separate Internet service and connectivity offered by different ISPs?

Tags: corda

We have come across a situation where each node may use separate "Internet service and Connectivity" offered by different ISPs. 
Can the nodes still communicate?

For example -

If node A is running in a machine that is connected to internet using "Sky Broadband" ISP

and

If node B is running in another machine that is connected to internet using "Vodafone Broadband" ISP -

Can node A and node B communicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "network". Corda has two types of network:

- *Business networks*: Groups of nodes running particular CorDapps. Each such group will often have a co-ordinating party - the *Business Network Operator* - who manages the distribution of the app and rules governing its use (including around membership of the business network)
- *Compatibility zones*: Group of nodes that are each identified using a certificate issued by the same certificate authority, and that are all identifiable on the network's *network map*

Nodes in different business networks can communicate freely without any special configuration.

As of Corda 4, nodes in different compatibility zones cannot communicate out-of-the-box. However, we are investigating mechanisms for cross-compatibility zone and cross-platform communication. You can read more about these efforts here: https://medium.com/corda/some-thoughts-on-compatibility-interoperability-and-integration-e1c6b3af3987.

EDIT: You comment below indicates that you were talking about nodes communicating when running on different ISPs. Yes, nodes can communicate across different IPs as long as they are connected to the internet and not running on a private network.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Here, by "Network" I meant - "internet broadband". 

Can nodes communicate with each other when they are using Internet service and connectivity offered by diferent internet broadband services?

For example - 
If node A is running in machine that is connected to internet using "Sky Broadband" ISP and 
if node B is running in machine that is connected to internet using "Vodafone Broadband" ISP, can they still communicate?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.