# Clarification on corda network type of cordapp example

Tags: corda

I m referring [Can corda nodes communicate when run from different networks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53872531/can-corda-nodes-communicate-when-run-from-different-networks)

I am looking at 3.3 opensource cordapp example and  could see the certificates are generated automatically while deployment with devmode=true.

Can I get information - whether it is configured with network type as **business network** or **compatibility zone** ?

Can I get more information on how to configure as a business network? is there any example?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `deployNodes` to create your nodes, you create a mini-compatibility zone of nodes running in `devMode`. Unlike a traditional compatibility zone, you need to use the Network Bootstrapper tool to manually add nodes to the network, rather than using the dyanmic joining process available in a compatibility zone with a central network map service.

A business network is a sub-group within a compatibility zone of nodes operating for a specific business purpose. A node can be part of multiple business networks. You can read more about business networks here: https://solutions.corda.net/business-networks/what-is-a-business-network.html.